# How to use .byCharWrapping for a specific character?

Tags: swift, uilabel, word-wrap

How would I do something similar to .byCharWrapping for a label where the text is in the form of "soccer", "basketball", "hockey", "volleyball" and I want to wrap by commas so that the displayed text would be e.g. "soccer", "basketball", "hockey" if "volleyball" doesn't fit within the label.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fit your text with another solution , you can also fit your text in label with font size : like below line and you can put it on if conditions :

```
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the actual width of string with font, then do whatever you want if that width is less than labels width.

See here [size(withAttributes:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1531844-size)